# How can I check if a user has uploaded photos to my image views in Kotlin android

Tags: kotlin

How can I check if a user has uploaded photos to my image views in Kotlin android, so that I can allow them to move to the next fragment. I want to include this in my on Apply function where I have including the other checks for is Null Or Empty for the text views. I have 4 image views I want the user to upload photos to. I want to check this in on apply function.

````
    private lateinit var userId: String
    private lateinit var userDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private var callback: TinderCallback?=null

    fun setCallback(callback: TinderCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
        userId= callback.onGetUserId()
        userDatabase= callback.getUserDatabase().child(userId)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        progressLayout.setOnTouchListener { view, event -> true  }

        populateInfo()
        photoIV.setOnClickListener{callback?.startActivityForPhoto()}
        image1IV.setOnClickListener{callback?.startActivityForPhoto1()}
        image2IV.setOnClickListener{callback?.startActivityForPhoto2()}
        image3IV.setOnClickListener{callback?.startActivityForPhoto3()}


        applyButton.setOnClickListener { onApply()}
        signoutButton.setOnClickListener{callback?.onSignOut()}
    }

    fun populateInfo(){
        progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        userDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(isAdded){
                    val user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                    nameET.setText(user?.name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    emailET.setText(user?.email, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    ageET.setText(user?.age, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    occupationET.setText(user?.occupation, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    countryET.setText(user?.country, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    cityET.setText(user?.city, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                    interestsET.setText(user?.interests, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

                    if(user?.gender == GENDER_MALE) {
                        radioMan1.isChecked = true
                    }
                    if (user?.gender == GENDER_FEMALE){
                        radioWoman1.isChecked = true
                    }

                    if(user?.preferredGender == GENDER_MALE) {
                        radioMan2.isChecked = true
                    }
                    if(user?.preferredGender == GENDER_FEMALE){
                        radioWoman2.isChecked = true
                    }
                    if (!user?.imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        populateImage(user?.imageUrl!!)
                    }
                    if (!user?.image1url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        populateImage1(user?.image1url!!)
                    }
                    if (!user?.image2url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        populateImage2(user?.image2url!!)
                    }
                    if (!user?.image3url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        populateImage3(user?.image3url!!)
                    }
                    progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            }

        })
    }

    private fun onApply(){
        if(nameET.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() ||
            ageET.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() ||
            emailET.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() ||
            radioGroup1.checkedRadioButtonId == -1 ||
            radioGroup2.checkedRadioButtonId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.error_profile_incomplete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            val name = nameET.text.toString()
            val age = ageET.text.toString()
            val email = emailET.text.toString()
            val occupation = occupationET.text.toString()
            val country = countryET.text.toString()
            val city = cityET.text.toString()
            val interests = interestsET.text.toString()

            val gender =
                if(radioMan1.isChecked) GENDER_MALE
                else GENDER_FEMALE

            val preferredGender =
                if(radioMan2.isChecked) GENDER_MALE
                else GENDER_FEMALE

            userDatabase.child(DATA_NAME).setValue(name)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_AGE).setValue(age)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_EMAIL).setValue(email)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_COUNTRY).setValue(country)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_CITY).setValue(city)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_OCCUPATION).setValue(occupation)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_INTERESTS).setValue(interests)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_GENDER).setValue(gender)
            userDatabase.child(DATA_GENDER_PREFERRENCE).setValue(preferredGender)

            callback?.profileComplete()
        }
    }

    fun updateImageUri(Uri:String){
        userDatabase.child(DATA_IMAGE_URL).setValue(Uri)
        populateImage(Uri)
    }
    fun updateImageUri1(Uri:String){
        userDatabase.child(DATA_PHOTO1_URL).setValue(Uri)
        populateImage1(Uri)
    }

    fun populateImage(Uri: String) {
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri)
            .into(photoIV)
    }
    fun populateImage1(Uri: String){
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri)
            .into(image1IV)

    }
    fun updateImageUri2(Uri:String){
        userDatabase.child(DATA_PHOTO2_URL).setValue(Uri)
        populateImage2(Uri)
    }
    fun populateImage2(Uri: String) {
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri)
            .into(image2IV)
    }
    fun updateImageUri3(Uri:String){
        userDatabase.child(DATA_PHOTO3_URL).setValue(Uri)
        populateImage3(Uri)
    }
    fun populateImage3(Uri: String) {
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri)
            .into(image3IV)
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

If those `populateImage` functions are where you add the images to the `ImageView`s, you could set an `imageAdded` `var` in there, one for each `ImageView`. Then your code can check if all 4 are set to true